# Rails: query results are not updated after changing data in sqlite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, sqlite, activerecord

I'm new to developing with Ruby on Rails and have some problems on creating a web application.

---

**< Behavior >**

1) I created some seed data.

2) Then I tried db:reset on a console.

3) I found that while data in the database (sqlite) are correctly updated, the view still has no change. What I wrote in the controller is as follows:

> @members = Member.order("number")

4) Then I added some extra data via my web application( not using console this time ) and found that the data showed upon the list in the view page although the data wasn't added to the database.

---

**< What I've tried >**

I've tried following actions:

1) I've also tried writing SQL in the database, and the result was same (correctly inserted into the database but didn't show upon the view page).

2) I've restarted httpd( I'm using Passenger ) and there were no changes.

3) I've added Member.reload / Member.reset_column_information like this:

> ```
> Member.reload
> @members = Member.order("number")
> ```

After writing this code the change are reflected only first time.

4) I've found after I overwrite a file under the /model/ directory, the change are reflected on view pages.

5) I've set config/environments/development.rb as follows:

> config.cache_classes = false

And nothing changes.

6) I've write following code on rails console:

> reload!

Nothing changes.

---

**< Questions >**

The questions are:

1) Why do these odd behavior happen?

2) Where does rails keep & add data without databases and how?

3) Is there any way to reflect updates into the view automatically after changing database by means of rake db:reset?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "data in the view didn't change"?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Member.connection.clear_query_cache
```

The reason for this to happen is that models have their internal SQL caching system, which helps avoiding calling some queries more than once.

In general it is quite intelligent and can pick the changes made through `ActiveRecord`, but won't be able to pick the changes made by an external process (console).

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation. The first time I've added your sample code it worked well, but next try ( changing seed data & typing db:reset ) with leaving the clear_query_cache code, there are no change again...

Comment: Because first time you run it it managed to cache the results again and it didn't go to the database for the second time. If you want rails to go to database for all queries try `Member.connection.disable_query_cache!`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Now I could understand the problem is about caching system. I'll also check the implementation of rails caching system.

Answer (score 0):

I think you aren't recovering data the right way. Try the following piece of code instead of @members = Member.order("number")

```
@members = Member.find(:all, :order => "number")
```

You should see the updates after doing rake db:reset, because the rake db:seed task is called automatically when you make a db reset.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The view has been changed at 1st try ( changing seed data & typing db:reset ), but after that it came to make no changes on the view... Is it because the query result is cached? Thank you for your help anyway.

Comment: Have you verified that the data has been written on your database? Maybe the error is the way the data is saved in your controller. You should read the log (log directory) to see what's been done. Also, check your model file to see if you have any restriction for the information you're saving. (Please, vote the answer if it helps :) )

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'll check the log data at once. And I'm really sorry but the system said that "Vote Up requires 15 reputation" so I couldn't vote... ( Actually I just registered stackoverflow yesterday ) however I'm really appreciate to you.

Comment: Don't worry about it :) 
I would try also to use the built-in rails server to see if the problem has to be with your Apache server. You can launch it with "rails server".

Comment: Thank you. I've just tried "rails server" instead of Passenger ( because I'm using VPS, I used reverse proxy via apache ). However the behavior still has no change... I'll check it again carefully and if I had some solutions I'll tell you at once.